# Trying to get a string value from native dll

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have a native dll that I need to set a string value of a parameter. Below is the c++ method signature

```
  __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall getDetails(_Out_ LPTSTR lpDetails, _In_ UINT uSize)
```

c++ method

I've hardcoded this for the return lpDetails=L"test";

My c# signature

```
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
   [DllImport("test.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
   static extern bool getDetails(StringBuilder result, System.UInt32 uSize);
```

c# code

```
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(1000);
        getDetails(b, 255);
        m = b.ToString(); //always ""
        Console.WriteLine(m);
```

When I step through the code I see the value (lpDetails) get set to the correct value. The problem is on the c# all I ever see is an empty string.

I have tried a things I found from other posts but so far no luck.

Comment: Did you just reassign the pointer `lpDetails`? You need to copy `L"test"` *into* the buffer. `wcstrcpy_s(lpDetails, 5, L"test");`

Comment: Is it really `_Out_ LPTSTR lpDetails` or `_Out_ LPTSTR* lpDetails`?
LPTSTR can't be an output parameter, unless you really want a single character to be returned, but then you wouldn't have `uSize` argument?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic Doesn't `_Out_` just mean that the flow of information is out? As you say, since the pointer itself can't be modified and a new pointer returned to the caller, `_Out_` just means that the function returns new data in the buffer which it is provided. And doesn't read the contents of the buffer that were passed in.

Comment: If it was really OUT, then it would mean that there is no need to send the correct pointer into function, which is obviously not a case, as we need a `strcpy`. So in this case it is really an IN_OUT parameter. If it was OUT, then it would need to be declared as LPTSTR*, so that it is enough to return the value from the function, regardless of what was `lpDetails' value before the call

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic You are incorrect. The parameter is the string rather than the pointer. And the string travels one way only. As an example, take a look at [`GetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520.aspx).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are right.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic Feel free to remove those parts of your otherwise fine answer

Comment: I am fresh as an SO member, so removing the incorrect part of my own answer still somehow feels like cheating :)

Answer (score 1):

There are few things wrong here:

- native method is shown with C signature, not C++ signature (I am
  nitpicking here :)
- lPDetails parameter is IN, not OUT, if you want
  function to write details to a preallocated location (as it seems
  from the second argument which should denote the length of the
  allocated buffer)
- your implementation `lpDetails=L"test"` is broken. If you provide the preallocated buffer to the function (as your signature implies) you need to `_tcscpy` the details into lpDetails. If you want to allocate the string inside the function (as your implementation implies, you need to declare lpDetails as `LPTSTR*`, but this is a bad design as caller might not now how to free it (and in this case indeed it cant as "test" points to a static memory in data segment and not to the heap.

This wouldn't work even without Interop:

```
LPTSTR pCallerData; // a pointer variable
void getDetails(LPTSTR lpData, /*what do you use second param for? */)
{
  // lpData is a COPY of pCallerData, not a pointer to it, 
  // so you are not modifying pCallerData, but a local variable
  lpData = "test";
  // after the function exits pCallerData still has the same value as before
}_
```

better implementation would be:

```
LPTSTR txt[256]; 
getDetails(txt, 256);
// ----
void getDetails(LPTSTR lpData, int size)
{
_tcscpy(lpDetails, _T("Test")); 
// or more realistically _tcsncpy and properly check 
// if details string is longer than size argument
}_
```

Comment: One more thing that I can see. The C# code declares a bool return type, but the C++ code has void return type.